# Using condition of case_when with function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
df<-data.frame(Id=seq(1,12),col1=c(rep('AA',5),rep('TT',3),rep('AT',4)),col2=c(rep('CC',5),rep('GG',3),rep('GC',4)),col3=c(rep('TT',5),rep('CC',3),rep('CT',4)),col4=c(rep('AA',2),rep('TT',4),rep('AT',6)))
# -----------------------
 Id col1 col2 col3 col4
   1   AA   CC   TT   AA
   2   AA   CC   TT   AA
   3   AA   CC   TT   TT
   4   AA   CC   TT   TT
   5   AA   CC   TT   TT
   6   TT   GG   CC   TT
   7   TT   GG   CC   AT
   8   TT   GG   CC   AT
   9   AT   GC   CT   AT
  10   AT   GC   CT   AT
  11   AT   GC   CT   AT
  12   AT   GC   CT   AT
```

I want to make conditions using if or `case_when` to do this:

```
new_col=
case_when 
col1=="A" and col2=="C" and col3=="T" and col4=="A" assign "01", 
col1=="A" and col2=="C" and col3=="T" and col4=="T" assign "02", 
col1=="T" and col2=="G" and col3=="C" and col4=="T" assign "03",
col1=="T" and col2=="G" and col3=="C" and col4=="A" assign "04",
col1=="T" and col2=="G" and col3=="T" and col4=="A" assign "05",
any other conition assign to "other"
```

The problem is there are 2 letters in each cell in my data so the out put should have 2 values
like this

```
 Id col1 col2 col3 col4    new_col
   1   AA   CC   TT   AA    01+01
   2   AA   CC   TT   AA    01+01
   3   AA   CC   TT   TT    02+02
   4   AA   CC   TT   TT    02+02
   5   AA   CC   TT   TT    02+02
   6   TT   GG   CC   TT    03+03
   7   TT   GG   CC   AT    04+03
   8   TT   GG   CC   AT    04+03
   9   AT   GC   CT   AT    01+03
  10   AT   GC   CT   AT    01+03 
  11   AT   GC   CT   AT    01+03  
  12   AT   GC   CT   AT    01+03
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to test every row for 5 conditions and if the statements is false which means non of the condition was found in the tested row, then the output shout be other.
I've been trying and all my trials has failed, can you please help me?

Comment: Do you want to compare each letter by position i.e letter 1 of col1 with letter 1 of col2 and so on? Or you want to compare them in any order? How do you get 05 in the last row?

Comment: @Ronak Shah, its not a comparison , I want if there is letter A in col1 and letter T in col2 and letter C in col3 and letter T in col4 then they all should be assigned as 01. So the precence of all of them to fulfil the condition.

Comment: The output is still not clear to me. For example, how is 7th row `04+02` ? 02 has col1 as A. There is no A on 7th row in col1.

Comment: @Ronak Shah, I'm so sorry i just noticed this and fixed, ill check them all again

Comment: So if the ordering does not matter, what happens when you have something like `AA CC TT AT`?? Will that be `01+01+02`? ie the first time we take only the first letters, the second time we take only the second letters but since ordering does not matter, in the last case of AT we take the first letter. Do you see how non-ordering complicates things?

Comment: @Onyambu, for this example `AA CC TT AT` the condition is if there is `A C T A `this will be type 1 and if there is `A C T T` then its type 2, its only 2 possible outputs. So it should find any letter in the col 1 the order of the letters is not important but the condition order is important. I'm sorry i know i havent dilevered the idea properly but its complex to explain!

Comment: So why would you not consider the answer to be `01+01+02`?? I mean we can get `01` multiple times and also `02` also the first one Why just `01+01` why not `01+01+01+01....` ? Don't you have to do permutation?

Comment: You claim the order does not matter but if you look at rows 7 & 8, you have 04+03 and not 03+04 meaning in a way you are taking order into consideration. If unordered, the solution space for your problem is exponential in nature.

Comment: @Onyambu, because the condition is that the for every row they must have the 4 letters inorder to give us type X(the condition), and becuase the every column has 2 letters , here we have 2 possible conditions either  `A C T A` that give us type x, and `A C T T` that give us type x2, for example .

Comment: The question is which `A` are you using for type 2. Is it the first `A` or the second `A`. ie you have `AA`. So are you using the first A or the second one  for 02?

Comment: @ Onyambu, any A, the order here is not imprtant for my analysis.

Comment: And that is the issue, when you say you can use any A, that means that `AT   CG   TC   AT` can be 01+04+other+other+..., since AGCT, AGTT etc are not defined. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Onyambu , yes thats true ,i have to think about this again because they must have only 2 possible combination, thanks for bringing this to my attention

Comment: @Onyambu  So what if you help me to do it with all the possible outcoms, please ? i mean for example, 01+02+03+other ...

Comment: That problem is exponential, but we can try it out, meaning for 12 rows, you will have to check 12* 2^4 outcomes.

Comment: So in row 12 for example, why dont you have `02`?? we can definately get `A C T T` from the sequence given

Comment: @Onyambu  , yes thats correct. this is just example in my data there are  more conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the conversation we had, here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Id)%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~list(unique(str_split(.x,'')[[1]]))))%>%
  reduce(names(df)[-1], ~unnest(.x, .y), .init = .) %>%
  mutate(res = case_when(col1=="A" & col2=="C" & col3=="T" & col4=="A" ~ "01", 
                   col1=="A" & col2=="C" & col3=="T" & col4=="T" ~ "02", 
                   col1=="T" & col2=="G" & col3=="C" & col4=="T" ~ "03",
                   col1=="T" & col2=="G" & col3=="C" & col4=="A" ~ "04",
                   col1=="T" & col2=="G" & col3=="T" & col4=="A" ~ "05",
                   TRUE ~ "other")) %>%
  summarise(res = str_c(unique(sort(res)), collapse = '+'))%>%
  right_join(df)%>%
  select(-res, everything(), res)

# A tibble: 12 x 6
      Id col1  col2  col3  col4  res                 
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>               
 1     1 AA    CC    TT    AA    01                  
 2     2 AA    CC    TT    AA    01                  
 3     3 AA    CC    TT    TT    02                  
 4     4 AA    CC    TT    TT    02                  
 5     5 AA    CC    TT    TT    02                  
 6     6 TT    GG    CC    TT    03                  
 7     7 TT    GG    CC    AT    03+04               
 8     8 TT    GG    CC    AT    03+04               
 9     9 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
10    10 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
11    11 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
12    12 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
```

### UPDATE:

```
vec <- c(ACTA = '01', ACTT ='02',TGCT = '03',TGCA = '04',TGTA = '05')
df %>%
  group_by(Id)%>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~list(unique(str_split(.x,'')[[1]]))))%>%
  reduce(names(df)[-1], ~unnest(.x, .y), .init = .) %>%
  mutate(res = coalesce(vec[invoke(paste0, across(col1:col4))], 'other'))%>%
  summarise(res = str_c(unique(sort(res)), collapse = '+'))%>%
  right_join(df)%>%
  select(-res, everything(), res)



    Id col1  col2  col3  col4  res                 
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>               
 1     1 AA    CC    TT    AA    01                  
 2     2 AA    CC    TT    AA    01                  
 3     3 AA    CC    TT    TT    02                  
 4     4 AA    CC    TT    TT    02                  
 5     5 AA    CC    TT    TT    02                  
 6     6 TT    GG    CC    TT    03                  
 7     7 TT    GG    CC    AT    03+04               
 8     8 TT    GG    CC    AT    03+04               
 9     9 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
10    10 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
11    11 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
12    12 AT    GC    CT    AT    01+02+03+04+05+other
```

Comment: That's awesome, I really appreciate your help, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi check the updated version